# Command usage parser using Boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

Consider this string `my_comamnd -A aaa {-B | -C} [-D -E]`

This defines a command with name `my_command`, that accepts one mandatory argument `-A aaa`, two mutual exclusive switches `{-B | -C}`(exactly one of them should be specified) and two optional switches `[-D -E]` (none or both should be specified.)

I need to write parser that will accept the usage string and will give some structure(maybe syntax tree) that will be used to create command.

I have some questions about it

- What is called that syntax? I am thinking about [Extended Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) but maybe it has more specific name. What is called the format that describes commands?
- I am thinking about using [Boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) library. Is it possible? I believe it is [Parsing Expression Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_Expression_Grammar). So it should be possible to write parser using Boost::spirit.
- Are there any parsers written in C++ that can parse such strings?

Comment: I don't think you need to use something as powerful & complex as spirit for a command line. I would just roll my own parser, taking items from the front of the string and checking for errors at the end.

Comment: @TimBergel It is not just command line, it is command definition. The string that is parsed, defines a command. `{{...}{...}{{...}[...[...]]}}` the options may be nested. Do you think it is easy to write parser from the scratch, than using boost::spirit ?

Comment: I think boost::spirit is intended for parsing complete grammars - the sort of thing a compiler does. A parser for a simple command line would almost certainly be easier to write by hand. A very complex one would certainly benefit from boost::spirit. Your line of text with nested options does not look complicated enough to require spirit, but I don't know what you mean by 'command definition'. Certainly I would be surprised if spirit could not do what you want - I just don't know if it would be the easiest option.

Comment: @Tim Boost.Spirit is just fine here. It’s definitely not only for complex grammars, and in fact it’s extremely efficient (there was a benchmark showing that Boost.Spirit is the most efficient way of parsing a single integer) and fairly easy to use for small grammars. Definitely worth considering.

Comment: Thank you Konrad - I live and learn.

Comment: The library I have come to use is boost::program_options.  They have examples that cover most of the things you are referring.  It is a well thought out library   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html